# remove hostname of image link in django REST API

Tags: django, django-models, django-serializer

I have a `model` like below:

```
# models.py
# ================================================
def get_category_image_name(instance, filename):
    fn = os.path.join('img/thumbnailCategory/ct', str(instance.id) + '.png')
    return fn

def get_food_t_image_name(instance, filename):
    fn = os.path.join('img/imgFood/ft', str(instance.id) + '.png')
    return fn


def get_food_d_image_name(instance, filename):
    fn = os.path.join('img/DDD_Food/fd', str(instance.id) + '.png')
    return fn


def id_generator(size=10, chars='123456789'):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))


class Category(models.Model):

    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=id_generator, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    c_thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_category_image_name, null=False, blank=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id = id_generator()
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s | %s' % (self.title, self.id)


class Food(models.Model):
    food_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=id_generator, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    category_id = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    f_thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_food_t_image_name)
    DDD_data = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_food_d_image_name)
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id = id_generator()
        super(Food, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.name, self.category_id, self.price)
```

I write a filter for foods that filter foods by category.

My `views.py` is like:

```
class GetListOfFoodsByCategory(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Food.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FoodSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('category_id',)
```

And my `urls.py` has:

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'food', views.GetListOfFoodsByCategory)
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

And my serializer simply is like:

```
class FoodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Food
        fields = '__all__'
```

My problem is:

When I run the project and see the links of food images, it shows me hostname/directory of images. I want to remove hostname from it. like below:
[image]

How can I remove it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override image field by using [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```
class FoodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    f_thumbnail = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    DDD_data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Food
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_f_thumbnail(self, obj):
        if obj.f_thumbnail:
            return obj.f_thumbnail.url

    def get_DDD_data(self, obj):
        if obj.DDD_data:
            return obj.DDD_data.url
```

Comment: @shahab I forgot about validation. Check updated answer, I added `if obj.DDD_data` validation. Without it Django will raise error if image is empty.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my case. But with this, the upload field button for that ImageField, is gone missing in API Viewer of DRF. What's the solution?

Comment: @swdev try to pverride serializer's `to_representation` method instead of `SerializerMethodField`.